# Enviar anexo vindo do formulario usando phpmailer com formData

Tags: php

tenho um formulario que recebe dados normais e anexo.
quando incluo o attachment o email nao passa, porem da mensagem de sucesso.
quando tiro a linha do attachment o email passa.
deixo o meu codigo.

Os campos assinalados com  *sao de preenchimento obrigatorio

Nome*

```
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                 <label for="name">Anexar Documentos<span>*</span></label>
                 <input type="file" class="form-control" id="anexo" required ng-model="atendimento.anexo">
                 
                 
                 </div>
                  
                
               <div class="form-group float-right">
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger pl-2 pr-2" ng-click="agendar()" >Enviar</button>
               </div>
               <br>
            </form>
    </div>
</div></strike>
```

````
    
    
    
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
           
        //Server settings
        //$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;            // Enable verbose debug output SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
        $mail->isSMTP();                                  // Send using SMTP
        $mail->Host       = '';            // Set the SMTP server to send through
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                         // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username   = '';     // SMTP username
        $mail->Password   = '';                 // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS; // Enable TLS encryption; 
        $mail->Port       = 587;   
  
          //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('', '');
        $mail->addReplyTo('', '');
        $mail->addAddress($formData->email);     // Add a recipient
        $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['anexo']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['anexo']['name']);   ```
````